# IllegalAnnotationExceptions while converting object to XML using Jaxb

Tags: jaxb

I have a `TrainingCalendarWrapper` class which have a list which hold `TrainingCalendarVO`. In my application
I'm setting the details in `TrainingCalendarVO` and then added to `trainingList` of `TrainingCalendarWrapper` 
And then converting `TrainingCalendarWrapper`  to `XML` using `Jaxb`.

```
@XmlRootElement
 public class TrainingCalendarWrapper implements Serializable
   {
      public ArrayList<TrainingCalendarVO> trainingList;
      Getters & Setters for trainingList
   }
```

*1 counts of illegalAnnotationException Class has two properties of the same name "trainingList" for the below line of code*
`JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TrainingCalendarWrapper.class);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are annotating the fields (instance variables) then you need to specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` at the class level.  Otherwise you can add the annotation to the `get` or `set` methods.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html